# nTop RRDalarm configuration

Tags: python, linux

I have `ntop v.5.0.1 (64 bit) [x86_64-2.6.32-5-amd64-linux-gnu]` installed from sources on a Debian Wheezy system.

I can't configure RRDalarm, when i go to "Tools / RRD Alarm / Configure Thresholds", I have a blank page.

When I go to "Tools / RRD Alarm / Check now", I have a 404 error

Here are the files and permissions:

```
root@ntop:/usr/local/share/ntop/python# ls -lR rrdalarm
rrdalarm:
total 40
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ntop root  6840 mai   23  2010 config.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ntop root   508 mars  15  2010 crontab.rrdalarm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ntop root  3060 mars  31  2010 save.py
drwxrwxr-x 2 ntop root  4096 août  13  2012 scripts
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ntop root 19051 mai   23  2010 start.py
rrdalarm/scripts:
total 16
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ntop root  1036 mars  31  2010 savelog.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ntop root 10793 mars  15  2010 sendmail.py
```

When I go to `http://IP_ADDR:3000/python/hello_world.py` this works.

I've searched Google with no success.

In logs I have:

```
[PYTHON] Executing import os
#012os.environ['DOCUMENT_ROOT']='/usr/local/share/ntop'
#012os.environ['REQUEST_METHOD']='GET'
#012os.environ['QUERY_STRING']=''
```

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Perhaps this should be on superuser?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i've launched the service as root, nothing changed.

Comment: Returning back launching as ntop user, this works! Thanks

Comment: Oh haha, I just realised why you thought I answered. I was actually suggesting you redirect this to the superuser Stack Exchange, since this didn't seem to be programming related. But hey, +1 for a correct misread.

Answer (score 0):

Running nTop as root solved the problem:

```
/usr/local/bin/ntop -d -L -u **root** -P /usr/local/etc/ntop --access-log-file /var/log/ntop/access.log -i br0,br1 -p /usr/local/etc/ntop/protocol.list -O /var/log/ntop
```